# The difference between compound words and genitive cases

Tags: possessives, compound-words

I have a problem with genitive cases and compound words, I don't understand the difference between a genitive case and a compound word (noun + noun structure). I was trying to understand them by googling but I couldn't find any answers. 
For example, is "bathroom floor" a compound word or a genitive case?
Can someone explain for me, please?

Thanks./

Comment: 'Bathroom' here is a premodifier of the head-noun 'floor'. 'Bathroom' is a noun used as a premodifier here, an 'attributive noun'. The string (a string is a sequence of 1 or 2 or 3 or ... words in a sentence say) 'bathroom floor' is perhaps a weak collocation. 'sillver lining' is a strong collocation, and 'peanut butter' is a compound noun, which will appear as a single lexeme in a dictionary. And 'pewter bracelet' is just a 'free combination', with no real cohesiveness between the words except in the odd example.

Comment: With no examples, we don't have any idea what you mean by "genitive cases" or "compound words".

Comment: What do you mean by a genitive case? Strictly speaking English doesn't have nouns in the genitive case. Loosely speaking it has something similar, the 's added to the end of a noun (or just an apostrophe if the noun is a regular plural), e.g. as in "the house's floor". But, as I say, strictly speaking, that is not a case marker.